# Strange placement of dessen in relative clause

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

> Denke dir ein Sprachspiel, in welchem B dem A **auf *dessen* Frage** die Anzahl der Platten, oder Würfel in einem Stoß meldet, oder die Farben
> und Formen der Bausteine, die dort und dort liegen
>
> 21.,  Page-13,Philosophical Investigations, Ludwig Wittgenstein

Could someone explain the placement of *dessen* in the first subordinate clause? I do know that, in a relative clause, a preposition such as *auf* comes before the relative pronoun but why does *in welchem B dem A* come before the preposition+ dessen?

Comment: First of all, the comma before "...oder Würfel" is wrong by today's rules

Comment: If you know, that *dessen* links the question back to *A* and that forward references are as clumsy in natural language as in programming, what remains as question?

Comment: Actually, you should be sorting out what you ask: The *position of dessen* and the *position of *in welchem B dem a thing before the preposition* are two different questions. It's unclear what's unclear to you.

Comment: I am asking about their relative positions @tofro

Comment: I didn't understand, how do you mean that forward references are clumsy? @guidot

Comment: I think it would make sense you try and describe what the sentence is trying to say - It might well be you didn't understand the sentence at all. Or, try to give an example what alternative word order you find more naturally. As it is, your question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a native German speaker, but I think I see what your question is.

> Denke dir ein Sprachspiel, in welchem B dem A (auf dessen Frage) die Anzahl der Platten oder Würfel in einem Stoß meldet oder die Farben und Formen der Bausteine, die dort und dort liegen...

If your question was why "dessen" is where it is, look at my version in parentheses.

"auf dessen Frage" refers to "A", so:

> Imagine a game where B tells A (to the latter's question) the number of...

Or, simply:

> Imagine a game where B tells A (while answering his, A's, question) the number of...

"Dessen" here means "the latter's", and "auf dessen" = "on the latter's", then "auf dessen Frage" = "on (to) the latter's question".

I suppose if in this sentence, instead of A and B, we used names or nouns of different genders, you could use "seine" instead of "dessen":

> Denke dir ein Sprachspiel, in welchem eine Lehrerin einem Studenten auf seine Frage die Anzahl meldet...

Or let's make it simpler:

> Die Lehrerin spricht mit einem Studenten. Sie antwortet auf seine Frage.

Compare it with a case where both nouns are of the same gender:

> Der Lehrer spricht mit einem Studenten. Er antwortet auf seine Frage.

Here, it's unclear whose question it is, so we have to use "dessen" instead of "seine" to show that it's the latter's question.

I'm not sure if the last two examples are the best illustration of the rule, but the takeaway is: if you have two subjects of the same gender and a possessive pronoun, you can use "dessen" with the meaning of "the latter's".

Hope this helps. Feel free to edit and comment.

Comment: Ill read this again 7-8 hours ( sleep)

Comment: Hmmm so, dessen is not just a relative pronoun O_o

Comment: *Dessen* is a demonstrative. The relative pronoun is *welchem*.

Comment: I think "dessen" is both demonstrative and relative (same as other definite articles). "Welchem" is an interrogative pronoun

Comment: Sorry, I was not exactly correct. "Welchem" can also serve as a demonstrative pronoun, see here: https://easy-deutsch.de/pronomen/relativpronomen/ But note that it says "Im Genitiv kann welche nicht benutzt werden. Im Nominativ, Dativ und Akkusativ gibt es aber keinen Unterschied zwischen „der“, „die“, „das“ und „welche“."

Comment: @ALÖ *Welchem* can be interrogative or relative, but here it is clearly a relative pronoun as there is no question. *Dessen* can be relative or demonstrative but the point here is that in the given sentence it is demonstrative. One instance of it cannot be both relative and demonstrative.

Comment: But could you use "welchem" in this example? "Denke dir ein Sprachspiel, in welchem B dem A (auf WELCHEM Frage) die Anzahl... meldet..." I think it is incorrect. If you were talking about the first "welchem" in the sentence (not the one that could be in place of "dessen"), then I don't see your point.

Comment: P.S. Yes, the first "welchem" is relative, but why would you mention it then?

Comment: @ALÖ Because the questioner seemed to think that *dessen* is the relative pronoun.

Comment: @RHa Ach so, stimmt.